# Convert <script> to <script setup lang="ts">

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I use the composition api with
`<script setup lang="ts">` for my project and I was needing this part of the vee-validate. But I am not entirely sure how to convert it.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-veevalidate-4-dynamic-rules-o9bgv?file=/src/App.vue:929-1002)